# Install4j service not started on machine reboot for Suse Enterprise Linux

Tags: install4j, sles

We have created an application using Install4j. This application has a service, created by using "Install a Service" action, with "auto start" attribute set.(The application launcher is a "Service" type with unix option "Auto-start service for Linux packages".)

For CentOS7, CentOS6, ,RHEL7, RHEL6 platforms the service starts automatically when the system is rebooted.

For Suse Enterprise Linux 12.x series, the service could not be started on system boot up. It is working fine, when invoked manually by command "/etc/init.d/{service-name} start".

When we check for the deployed files, the service file is copied to /etc/init.d/ folder and corresponding entries K50{service-name}, S50{service-name} files created at /etc/init.d/rc2.d/, /etc/init.d/rc3.d/, /etc/init.d/rc4.d/, /etc/init.d/rc5.d/. The service is turned on by chkconfig for 2,3,4,5 run levels. But when we reboot the machine, this particular service is not even attempted in the startup process.

Please suggest.

Comment: You mean the start script not not called at all? That would point to an incorrect configuration of the init system. Or is there simply an error when the start script is called?

Comment: The start script not called at all.

Comment: So then it must be related to the init system and not to the start script

Comment: ok. will check that..